# Header image not showing on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, themes

I made some changes on my theme and I must have messed it up! My header image is only showing half way... where would the problem be?
 I have tried so many things, nothing I do fixes the problem,
If follows my URL : [www.vincihairclinic.net](http://www.vincihairclinic.net)

**This is my header code:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <?php /* The navigation menu */ ?>
    <div id="header-menu-wrap" class="clearfix">
        <?php
        /* Header menu */
        $args = array(
            'container' => '',
            'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
            'menu_class' => graphene_get_menu_class( 'menu clearfix' ),
            'fallback_cb' => 'graphene_default_menu',
            'depth' => 5,
            'theme_location' => 'Header Menu',
        );
        if ( ! $graphene_settings['disable_menu_desc'] )
            $args = array_merge( $args, array( 'walker' => new Graphene_Description_Walker() ) );

        wp_nav_menu( apply_filters( 'graphene_header_menu_args', $args ) ); ?>
```

**This is my style.css code:**

```
 #header-menu-wrap 
        position: relative; 

    margin-top: -325px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 50;
    padding-left: 1px;

}

#header-menu 
    display: table !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.have-secondary-menu #header-menu-wrap 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.dropdown #header-menu-wrap 
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
#header-menu,
#secondary-menu 
    margin: 0 10px;
    z-index: 20;
}
#header-menu > li 
    font: normal 14px arial;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#header-menu > li:first-child 
    margin-left: 0;
}
#header-menu > li > a 
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 9px 10px 10px;
}
#header-menu > li > a > .desc 
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
}
#header-menu > li.menu-item-ancestor > a {
    background: url(images/sprite_master.png) -877px -236px no-repeat transparent;
    padding-left: 26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given css property which is issue.Remove it and see

```
.header-img 
{
  margin-left:-489px
}
```

Comment: I have tried removing all my updates, nothing fixes this problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug in or other theme option set which is changing the margin-left styling for `.header-img`. I looked at the Graphene theme and didn't see anything in the theme which would do that so it's probably a plugin. The `.header-img` is a common css class in WordPress themes.

Comment: Thanks JDP, I have tried disabling all plugins and it didn't change...don't know what else to do. There is no .header-img mention on my stylesheet.css file anywhere

Comment: It's in style.css but it's being overridden by something in the theme (see line 60 of your home page source).